# How to validate and wrap error message around input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-validate

I use the great jQuery validate plugin on my inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
```

I would like to add this structure (add a div.error around my input and display my error label inside the div), something like this:

```
<div class="error">
   <label id="name-error" class="error" for="name">This field is required.</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
</div>
```

I've try to play with errorPlacement function but I can't make it.

Comment: Please be more specific with what you need help with.

Comment: You need to show the rest of the relevant code, your jQuery call to the `.validate()` method, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery Validate plugin automatically creates and toggles an error message element.

1. You can specify the type of element, such as `div`, `label`, etc. using [the `errorElement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorelement).  Default is `label`.
2. You can specify the placement of this error message element, such as before, after, inside a parent, etc. using various jQuery methods inside [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement).  Default is "after" the `input` element.

However, you cannot easily wrap the error message element around the `input` element.  While it's possible to use jQuery to do this within the `errorPlacement` option, the problem occurs when the error needs to be cleared.  The plugin will automatically remove/hide the error message element when the message needs to be cleared and your `input` element will be removed/hidden along with it.

The solution would be to create the outer `div` yourself and use the [`highlight`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) and [`unhighlight`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#unhighlight) options to toggle the error class on this outer `div`.  You'll have to remember to also include the default code within `highlight` and `unhighlight` or the default behavior will be broken.  Since your desired class is the default error class, you can simply use the `errorClass` argument within the `highlight` and `unhighlight` options.

**Your HTML**:

```
<div>
   <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
</div>
```

**Your `.validate()` method**:

```
$('#yourForm').validate({
    // rules and options,
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertBefore(element);
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass); // <- default behavior
        $(element).parent('div').addClass(errorClass); // <- add error class to your parent div
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass); // <- default behavior
        $(element).parent('div').removeClass(errorClass); // <- remove error class from your parent div
    }
});
```

**The end result in the DOM during a validation error**:

```
<div class="error">
   <label id="name-error" class="error" for="name">This field is required.</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should play with [highlight](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) handler, which allows you to define a way of  marking input as invalid:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function(element, error, valid){
        $(element).parent("div").addClass(error); 
        // or do whatever you want
    }
});
```

please note that there is also another handler called `unhighlight` which should be also implemented but in opposite way to first one. Here you have an example of it:

```
unhighlight: function(element, error, valid){
    $(element).parent("div").removeClass(error); 
    // or do whatever you want but in opposite way
}
```

Full solution for your problem should looks like this:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function(element, error, valid){
        $(element).parent("div").addClass(error); 
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, error, valid){
        $(element).parent("div").removeClass(error); 
    }
});
```

Please note that code above should be included on site preferably after your jquery.validation.js, because it changing default behaviour of jQuery.validator.  Advantage of doing it through `jQuery.validator.setDefaults` is that your configuration will be applied on every single Form on your web site,

Comment: thnx, your answer is perfect for asp.net mvc where we don't call .validate directly and rely on defaults only